# Avoid multiple instances of TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a `TabBarController` and there are a few places in my app where a user can navigate completely outside of it. When they do, to bring them back I typically just call :

```
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            BottomTabsViewController *mainview=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainTabVC"];
            mainview.selectedIndex=3;
            mainview.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
            [self presentViewController:mainview animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but checking our API log, I am seeing some users making double and sometimes triple API calls to identical API functions leading me to believe that there are multiple instances of the same view controller floating around causing double load times and double everything.

How can I avoid this and make sure there is only one instance of my `TabBarController` at any given time?